# thickbox + google map does not show up?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, lightbox, thickbox

I have this HTML in my DNN pane:

```
<div class="mapImage"><span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><a href="#TB_inlinemodalContent?height=350&amp;width=500&amp;inlineId=modalContent"><img alt="" width="193" height="235" src="/Portals/5/home-3_03.png" /></a></span></div>

<a href="#TB_inlinemodalContent?height=400&amp;width=430&amp;inlineId=modalContent" title="add a caption to title attribute / or leave blank" class="thickbox">Show hidden modal content.</a>

<div id="modalContent" style="display: none;">
<iframe width="500" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=E11+4YE&amp;aq=&amp;sll=52.155202,-0.476543&amp;sspn=0.003864,0.011362&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=London+E11+4YE,+United+Kingdom&amp;ll=51.557596,0.004206&amp;spn=0.018677,0.042915&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=E11+4YE&amp;aq=&amp;sll=52.155202,-0.476543&amp;sspn=0.003864,0.011362&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=London+E11+4YE,+United+Kingdom&amp;ll=51.557596,0.004206&amp;spn=0.018677,0.042915&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
</div>
```

but all that comes is a black box as if the thickbox is trying to open. but no map shows?
any ideas? I want the map to appear when i click the image on my webpage.

any other light boxes that actually work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear enclose your div content inside p tag i.e 
`<div id="modalContent" style="display: none"> <p> your text and images etc... </p> </div>`